# How do I color output text from Perl script on Windows?

Tags: perl, winapi, console

I would like to color format the text printed to the console using the Perl print command.

In my case the script will only be run under WinXP-DOS Command Line but it would be great if it was OS independent although I would rather tie it to WinXP than have to download a seperate package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For any terminal that supports [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) you can use the [Term::ANSIColor package](http://search.cpan.org/dist/ANSIColor/ANSIColor.pm) available on CPAN.

From the Wikipedia page:

> Console windows in Windows versions
>   based on NT (Windows NT 4.0, Windows
>   2000, Windows XP, Windows Server 2003,
>   Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008)
>   do not natively support ANSI Escape
>   sequences, though some support is
>   possible.

Don't know any more Windows-specific information than that, I'm a POSIX guy. :-)

Comment: See also http://search.cpan.org/~jlmorel/Win32-Console-ANSI-1.04/lib/Win32/Console/ANSI.pm

Comment: I messed around with just using Term::ANSIColor but it was only printing the escape sequences...not properly showing the colors. I downloaded and built the package suggested by Hasturkun (http://search.cpan.org/~jlmorel/Win32-Console-ANSI-1.04/) and everything started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

[Win32::Console](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-Console) - here's an example

```
use Win32::Console;
my $CONSOLE = Win32::Console->new(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
my $attr = $CONSOLE->Attr(); # Get current console colors
$CONSOLE->Attr($FG_YELLOW | $BG_GREEN); # Yellow text on green

print "This is a test\n";

$CONSOLE->Attr($attr); # Set console colors back to original
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is what worked best for me after all:

1) Installed Win32::Console::ANSI (note that this is not the same as Win32::Console)

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan> install Win32::Console::ANSI
```

2) If this module is loaded before Term::ANSIColor, you can use the standard Term::ANSIColor API and it actually works (I tried it with Windows 7).

```
use Win32::Console::ANSI;
use Term::ANSIColor;

print color("blue"), "blue\n", color("reset");
print "normal\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
system("color A"); #DOS command, change text color to lime

system("color 7"); #DOS command, change text color to white
```

However those commands change text color on the whole screen. Type "color ?" in DOS window to see color options

I am using strawberry perl on Windows and I did not have Win32::Console package. To install this package type in console:

perl -MCPAN -e shell

install Win32::Console

exit

Answer (score 1):

building off of mphuie's Example, making it more cross-platform:

```perl
    use Term::ANSIColor;
    use Win32::Console;

    if ($^O =~ /win/) {
        our $FG_BLUE;
        our $FG_YELLOW;
        our $FG_RED;
        our $BG_GREEN;
        my $CONSOLE = Win32::Console->new(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        my $attr = $CONSOLE->Attr(); # Get current console colors
        $blue   = sub {$CONSOLE->Attr($FG_BLUE);return};
        $reset  = sub {$CONSOLE->Attr($attr);return};
        $yellow = sub {$CONSOLE->Attr($FG_YELLOW);return};
        $red    = sub {$CONSOLE->Attr($FG_RED);return};
    } else {
        $blue   = sub {return color('bold blue')};
        $reset  = sub {return color('reset')};
        $yellow = sub {return color('yellow')};
        $red    = sub {return color('red')};
    }
```

Quick note though: The Terminal colors do not change immediately when the functions are called from inside strings, thus:

```perl
    print "${\$blue->()} this is blue\n";
    print "${\$blue->()}This is... not blue${\$reset->()}\n";
    print "this is Blue ${\$blue->()}\n";
    print "this is reset${\$reset->()}\n";
```