# Coloring Perl output on windows command prompt

Tags: windows, perl, cmd, colors, windows-console

This question is related to the question:
[How do I color output text from Perl script on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087248/how-do-i-color-output-text-from-perl-script-on-windows/58645659#58645659)

But is a bit more specific. I have gotten cross-platform colorization working, to some extent:

```perl
use Term::ANSIColor;
use Win32::Console;

if (!(-f STDOUT)) {
    if ($^O =~ /win/) {
        our $FG_BLUE;
        our $FG_YELLOW;
        our $FG_RED;
        our $BG_GREEN;
        my $CONSOLE = Win32::Console->new(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        my $attr = $CONSOLE->Attr(); # Get current console colors
        $blue   = sub {$CONSOLE->Attr($FG_BLUE);return};
        $reset  = sub {$CONSOLE->Attr($attr);return};
        $yellow = sub {$CONSOLE->Attr($FG_YELLOW);return};
        $red    = sub {$CONSOLE->Attr($FG_RED);return};
    } else {
        $blue   = sub {return color('bold blue')};
        $reset  = sub {return color('reset')};
        $yellow = sub {return color('yellow')};
        $red    = sub {return color('red')};
    }
}
```

but The Terminal colors do not change immediately when the functions are called from inside strings, thus:

```perl
    print "${\$blue->()} this is blue\n";
    print "${\$blue->()}This is... not blue${\$reset->()}\n";
    print "this is Blue ${\$blue->()}\n";
    print "this is reset${\$reset->()}\n";
```

I am wondering if it is possible to do things such as:

```perl
    my $print_help = <<PRINT_HELP;
    Usage:  $toolname [-Options] [-fields name1,[name2],...]
    ${\$red->()} toolname version VERSION ${\$reset->()} 
    ${\$blue->()} options: ${\$reset->()}

    PRINT_HELP

    print $print_help;
```

prints with no colors. I have tried setting $| = 1 with no luck.

I do not have the option to install Win32::Console::ANSI on the system in question, so I am not able to make any solutions that use that module work.

Comment: If you put the heredoc end string in double quotes, I believe you'll get variable expansion that's not happening now. ie `<<"PRINT_HELP"` is functionally different than what you have now.

Comment: Unfortunately it appears that having the heredoc in quotes does not affect functionality in this case. Variable expansion was already occurring in the heredoc, it is just the subroutines are all executing before anything prints out. Since the color changes are being made at the time of the function call, rather than printing out a special character, all the changes are made before any of the text gets printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `red`, `reset`, `blue` and `reset` before you even start printing. You could use a template. Here's a robust implementation:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib "$RealBin/lib";

use My::Console qw( );

my $console = My::Console->new;

my $print_help = <<'__END_OF_HELP__';
Usage:  $toolname [-Options] [-fields name1,[name2],...]
{{red}}toolname version VERSION{{reset}}
{{blue}}options:{{reset}}

__END_OF_HELP__

$console->print_with_color($print_help);
```

`lib/My/Console.pm`:

```
package My::Console;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $console;
BEGIN {
   if (!-t STDOUT) {
      require My::Console::Dumb;
      $console = My::Console::Dumb::;
   }
   elsif ($^O eq 'Win32') {
      require My::Console::Win32;
      $console = My::Console::Win32::;
   }
   else {
      require My::Console::ANSI;
      $console = My::Console::ANSI::;
   }
}

sub new { $console }

1;
```

`lib/My/Console/Base.pm`:

```
package My::Console::Base;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Carp qw( croak );

my %allowed_cmds = map { $_ => 1 } qw( red blue reset );

sub red   { }
sub blue  { }
sub reset { }

sub print { print(STDOUT @_); }

sub print_with_color {
   my $self = shift;

   for (@_) {
      /\G ( (?: [^{] | \{(?!\{) )+ ) /xgc
         and $self->print($1);

      /\G \z /xgc
         and next;

      /\G \{\{ /xgc;

      /\G ( (?: [^}] | \}(?!\}) )* ) \}\} /xgc
         or croak("Bad template");

      my $cmd = $1;
      if ($cmd eq "") {
         # An escape mechanism. Use "{{}}" to output "{{".
         $self->print("{{");
         redo;
      }

      $allowed_cmds{$cmd}
         or croak("Unrecognized command \"$cmd\"");

      $self->$cmd();
      redo;
   }
}

1;
```

`lib/My/Console/Win32.pm`:

```
package My::Console::Win32;

use strict;
use warnings;

use My::Console::Base qw( );
use Win32::Console;

our @ISA = My::Console::Base::;

my $CONSOLE = Win32::Console->new(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
my $initial_console_attr = $CONSOLE->Attr();

sub red   { STDOUT->flush; $CONSOLE->Attr($FG_RED); }
sub blue  { STDOUT->flush; $CONSOLE->Attr($FG_BLUE); }
sub reset { STDOUT->flush; $CONSOLE->Attr($initial_console_attr); }

1;
```

`lib/My/Console/ANSI.pm`:

```
package My::Console::ANSI;

use strict;
use warnings;

use My::Console::Base qw( );
use Term::ANSIColor   qw( );

our @ISA = My::Console::Base::;

sub red   { print(Term::ANSIColor::red()); }
sub blue  { print(Term::ANSIColor::blue()); }
sub reset { print(Term::ANSIColor::reset()); }

1;
```

`lib/My/Console/Dumb.pm`:

```
package My::Console::Dumb;

use strict;
use warnings;

use My::Console::Base qw( );

our @ISA = My::Console::Base::;

1;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of the `::` at the end of `our @ISA = My::Console::Base::` ? Why not just `our @ISA = My::Console::Base`?

Comment: @HåkonHægland That's not valid Perl (unless strict is turned off)

Comment: Hmm.. according to [perlbobj](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) it should be valid? Also [perlmod](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Symbol-Tables) mentions symbol tables that are stored in hashes with the same name as the package with two colons appended. But it does not mention that these hashes are to be used in `@ISA`. Also I could not find any examples on google that uses `@ISA` in that way... Am I missing something?

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, I don't see why you think any of that is relevant, or why you think package names are valid expressions, but [they're not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58263206/589924). Just like `my $x = foo;` is generally an error under strict, so is my `$x = Foo::Bar;`. (`My::Console::Base` would be valid if it named a sub, but that would be produce the wrong result since we're trying to produce the string `My::Console::Base`.)

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I agree, I meant `our @ISA = qw(My::Console::Base)` not `our @ISA = My::Console::Base`.

Comment: @Håkon Hægland, The way I used is shorter, and will warn if you provide a non-existing package. It is otherwise equivalent (returns the string `My::Console::Base`).

Comment: @ikegami Although your solution is elegant and works well, I am looking for  a standalone script implementation for my usage case. Thank you for the great answer though!

Comment: It's already setup to look for module in the same directory as the script. But you could always inline the modules. You would have to make some changes to avoid loading Win32::Console on non-Windows machines, though. The reason I wrote the code i did was to avoid such problems

Answer (score 2):

This sort of hack might be along the lines of what you need.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $alice = sub  { return 'ALICE'; };

my $bob = sub { return 'BOB'; };

my $test = <<'ENDTEST';
lineone
line2 ${\$alice->()} endline
line3 startline ${\$bob->()}
linefour
linefive
ENDTEST

# Add spaces around newline, split on horizontal whitespace
$test =~ s/\n/ \n /g;
my @testtokens = split /\h/, $test;

# Print '%s ' for each of the testtokens
# Print newlines, evaluate all testtokens beginning with '$', otherwise print
map { /\n/ ? print : printf '%s ', /^\$/ ? eval $_ : $_} @testtokens;
```

Takes the ENDTEST heredoc and prints this on the last line:

```
$ heretest.pl
lineone 
line2 ALICE endline 
line3 startline BOB 
linefour 
linefive
```

*Maybe* that will evaluate things in order.

Comment: This solution does have some pitfalls, IE: you need to put spaces on the end of the line if the next line starts with a variable, and you need spaces after variables, but doing something similar, except splitting on curly braces may work better. Thanks for a solution!

Answer (score 0):

my console does not support colors but I can see ESCAPE codes which on console which supports colors should work. I do wonder if it works for you?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Term::ANSIColor;
use Win32::Console;

if (!(-f STDOUT)) {
    if ($^O =~ /win/) {
        our $FG_BLUE;
        our $FG_YELLOW;
        our $FG_RED;
        our $BG_GREEN;
        my $CONSOLE = Win32::Console->new(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        my $attr = $CONSOLE->Attr(); # Get current console colors
        $blue   = sub {$CONSOLE->Attr($FG_BLUE);return};
        $reset  = sub {$CONSOLE->Attr($attr);return};
        $yellow = sub {$CONSOLE->Attr($FG_YELLOW);return};
        $red    = sub {$CONSOLE->Attr($FG_RED);return};
    } else {
        $blue   = sub {return color('bold blue')};
        $reset  = sub {return color('reset')};
        $yellow = sub {return color('yellow')};
        $red    = sub {return color('red')};
    }
}

help();

sub help {
    print 
"
    Usage:  $toolname [-Options] [-fields name1,[name2],...]
    ${\$red->()} toolname version VERSION ${\$reset->()} 
    ${\$blue->()} options: ${\$reset->()}

";
}
```

Question: why do not use [POD](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html) for this purpose?

Comment: so far as I can tell, POD would probably work for this, but I have not worked with it before. I'll look into it, thanks~